AWS route53 domain cannot be resolved using an alias record pointing to an eks load balancer
I have configured an EKS cluster on AWS using terraform and it works totally fine. On that cluster, I created a simple nginx deployment exposed by a service which in turn, is exposed by an ingress. I can reach the landing page of that nginx server, i.e.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>

by running curl <http://dns_name_of_eks_load_balancer> where I retrieve the dns_name_of_eks_load_balancer by running kubectl get svc -n nginx-ingress and looking for the external IP of the service of type LoadBalancer. By the way, nginx-ingress is the namespace, into which I deployed an nginx ingress controller using the Helm provider of terraform.
Now, instead of using curl <http://dns_name_of_eks_load_balancer>, I want to use curl http://trading-bot.kevinsuedmersen.org to be redirected to the nginx server, where kevinsuedmersen.org is the domain I registered on AWS route53 and trading-bot.kevinsuedmersen.org should be a subdomain created by terraform. Following is the corresponding terraform code which should achieve this:
resource "aws_route53_zone" "primary_hosted_zone" {
  name = "kevinsuedmersen.org"
}

data "kubernetes_service" "load_balancer" {
  metadata {
    name = "nginx-ingress-controller"
    namespace = "nginx-ingress"
  }
}

data "aws_elb_hosted_zone_id" "hosted_zone_id" {}

resource "aws_route53_record" "trading_bot_record" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.primary_hosted_zone.zone_id
  name    = "trading-bot.kevinsuedmersen.org"
  type    = "A"

  alias {
    name                   = data.kubernetes_service.load_balancer.status[0].load_balancer[0].ingress[0].hostname
    zone_id                = data.aws_elb_hosted_zone_id.hosted_zone_id.id
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}

output "hosted_zone_name" {
  value = aws_route53_zone.primary_hosted_zone.name
}

output "hosted_zone_id" {
  value = aws_route53_zone.primary_hosted_zone.id
}

output "load_balancer_hostname" {
  value = data.kubernetes_service.load_balancer.status[0].load_balancer[0].ingress[0].hostname
}

output "load_balancer_hosted_zone_id" {
  value = data.aws_elb_hosted_zone_id.hosted_zone_id.id
}


However after running terraform apply and then curl trading-bot.kevinsuedmersen.org I always get the error

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: trading-bot.kevinsuedmersen.org

so I think there must be some sort of problem in the domain resolution.
I read through the corresponding terraform documentation and aws documentation, but I cannot find any errors, so any help is much appreciated!
PS: Just for completeness, here is the terraform code which provisions the nginx-ingress controller and the load balancer:
resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress" {
  name       = "nginx-ingress-controller"
  namespace = "nginx-ingress"
  create_namespace = true

  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart      = "nginx-ingress-controller"

  set {
    name  = "service.type"
    value = "LoadBalancer"
  }

  depends_on = [module.eks]
}

output "nginx_ingress_manifest" {
  value = helm_release.nginx_ingress.manifest
}

and here are the kubernetes configuration files for the simple nginx deployment, service and ingress
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2024-09-13T18:45:03Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: nginx-deployment
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1634842"
  uid: c3918ec9-7281-467d-818a-b2b36b21c837
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-deployment
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: nginx-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: nginx
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: nginx-deployment
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx-deployment
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - #  TODO: host: "trading-bot.kevinsuedmersen.org"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-service
            port:
              number: 80


I tried using dig to get the information about the domain, but it returns SERVFAIL. However, when I used the +trace option it returned the results for NS records.

Hi @MarkoE, thanks for your comment. So, that means that the domain should be resolvable into an IP address?

Nope, that means I can only get the nameservers for your domain.

Hmm alrgith, thanks for explaining. Would it help you if I provide the actual dns_name of the eks load balancer, so that you can curl into it and see the starting page of the nginx server? I'm just a bit hesitant, cause I don't know if it's a good idea to expose the dns_name of the load balancer on the internet

Please don't. Not sure what the reason might be, but you can check the status of your domain in Route53 console.

Hi @MarkoE, I was able to query the dns name of the eks load balancer using the kubernetes provider of terraform and I supplied more background information. Does it help you narrow down the issue a little bit?
